# How do I verify if required command is missing when running bash script?

Tags: bash, loops, command

I have following code to check missing commands:

```
 All commands
 ALLCMD=(
 route
 ip
 netstat
 tar
 )

 for cmd in ${ALLCMD[*]}
  do
  if ! command -v $cmd &> /dev/null
  then
  echo "Installed"
  echo "$cmd"
  else
  echo "Missing"
  echo "$cmd"
  fi
 done
```

I need to display only missing command and as it was advices problem was solved by removing Installed section

Comment: How is this unclear? Don't print in the found case.

Comment: What do you think `echo "Installed"` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `if` statement in the loop and both the positive case (condition met) and the negative case (condition not met) print something. If you don't want these, just remove them. That said, if you just remove the `echo` commands from the `if`, bash will complain:

> syntax error near unexpected token `else'

You can remove the `else` branch without problems. So you have to flip around your `if`'s condition. In your case it already negates the condition using the `!`, so you can just remove that:

```
if command -v "$cmd" &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Missing"
    echo "$cmd"
fi
```